Praat Scripting: Extract and Save Visible Pitch Contours in Bulk
I am working with many sound files (~300) and I need to extract and save the visible pitch contours for each sound file. I am doing this manually by opening each Sound object individually in Praat and clicking Pitch > Extract visible pitch contour, then renaming the Pitch object to match the original sound file, and saving the Pitch object. This is very time consuming, so I am wondering if anyone knows of (or knows how to write) a Praat script which can accomplish this in bulk?
In other words:

Load and select all sound objects
For each sound object, extract its visible Pitch contour to a pitch
object that bears the same name as  the associated sound object
Save the pitch object to the same directory as the Sound object

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!
